# Oracle BPM Application - Issue while deploying to Weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic, business-process-management

I am trying to deploy a reasonably complex Oracle BPM application (BPMN) to Weblogic 10.3.4 server installed on RHLinux 5. The issue is I am getting a connection timeout exception in the deployment log and hence the deployment fails.

After googling through, I tried to increase the timeout value of JTA through weblogic console but this did not help.

Following is the deployment log in jDeveloper:

```
[11:44:33 PM] Preparing to send HTTP request for deployment

[11:44:33 PM] Creating HTTP connection to host:localhost, port:7001

[11:44:33 PM] Sending internal deployment descriptor

[11:44:33 PM] Sending archive - sca_BPM_rev1.0.jar

Connection to the server timed out. Please check the server log for problems or increase the timeout value.

[12:03:43 AM] Error deploying archive sca_BPM_rev1.0.jar to partition "default" on server AdminServer [http://localhost:7001] 

[12:03:43 AM] HTTP error code returned [-1]

[12:03:43 AM] No error message is returned from the server.

[12:03:43 AM] Error deploying archive sca_BPM_rev1.0.jar to partition "default" on server AdminServer [http://localhost:7001] 

[12:03:43 AM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####

Error log from Weblogic Console:

May 19, 2011 12:11:28 AM PDT Error oracle.soa.bpel.engine BEA-000000 Unable to activate process IntraFirmTransfer
javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction Rolledback.: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 303 seconds
BEA1-0E886C94EA7C131B76F3
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionImpl.java:1748)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.processTimedOutTransactions(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1591)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.TransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(TransactionManagerImpl.java:1911)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionManagerImpl.wakeUp(ServerTransactionManagerImpl.java:1501)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.WLSTimer.timerExpired(WLSTimer.java:35)
        at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
; nested exception is: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 303 seconds
BEA1-0E886C94EA7C131B76F3
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.throwEJBException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:154)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.postInvoke1(BaseLocalObject.java:595)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_postInvokeTxRetry(BaseLocalObject.java:455)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:52)
        at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.ejb.impl.BPMNServerManagerBean_6gbx7k_ICubeServerManagerLocalBeanImpl.deployComponent(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.fabric.CubeServiceEngine.load(CubeServiceEngine.java:885)
```

Can someone throw some hints at the possible causes ?

Answer (score 0):

1) What is the hosts file setting for 'localhost'?

2) What is the listen address that you have in your Admin Server?  Make sure this is in line with the setting in the hosts file.

3) Can you telnet to the 7001 port on 'localhost'?  The command is [telnet localhost 7001]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are following the below Rule in terms of Transactions Timeout.

DB Distribution timeout > XA > JTA timouts.